# List of Codified Laws from Around the World in Structured Format?

Tags: europe, legal, asia, north-america, south-america

I am wondering where can one find datasets with all the laws on Earth (or all the laws from every country).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much but am wondering the same thing. [Here](https://www.loc.gov/research-centers/law-library-of-congress/researcher-resources/databases/) are some resources to start, from the Library of Congress (copied for reference):

### Free

- [American State Papers, 1789-1838](https://memory.loc.gov/ammem/amlaw/lwsp.html) (*Contains the legislative and executive documents of Congress for the period 1789 to    1838.*)
- [Avalon Project](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/) (*Digital    primary source documents selected by the Yale Law School relevant to the fields of Law,    History, Economics, Politics, Diplomacy and Government.*)
- [Congress.gov](http://congress.gov/) (*Contains full-text of legislation from the 103rd   Congress (1993) to the present and member profiles from the 93rd Congress   (1973) to the present.*)
- [Congressional Record](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/browse/collection.action?collectionCode=CREC) (*Contains    the official record of the proceedings and debates of the United States    Congress from Volume 140 (1994) to the present.*)
- [Foreign Relations of the United States (FRUS)](http://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments) (*U.S. Department of State site presenting the official documentary historical record of major United States foreign policy decisions and significant diplomatic activity, primarily covering 1945 to 1980.*)
- [Guide to Law Online](https://www.loc.gov/research-centers/law-library-of-congress/researcher-resources/databases/) (*Vast    network of links to content-based Web sites of primary and secondary legal    information from foreign jurisdictions and all U.S. federal, state and    territorial government entities.*)
- [Historical American Indian Constitutions and Legal Material](https://www.loc.gov/collections/) (*Digital copies of historical American Indian constitutions and other legal material, some in the vernacular languages of the tribes.*)
- [NCSL    State Legislative Websites Directory](http://www.ncsl.org/aboutus/ncslservice/state-legislative-websites-directory.aspx) (*Searchable    database providing links to Web sites of State Legislatures, Legislators and    political developments.*)
- [OYEZ](http://www.oyez.org/) (*A multimedia database about the United States Supreme Court which includes audio files of oral arguments, abstracts of key constitutional cases, and    information on Supreme Court justices.*)
- [Precedents of the U.S. House of Representatives (FDsys)](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/browse/collection.action?collectionCode=GPO&browsePath=Precedents+of+the+U.S.+House+of+Representatives&isCollapsed=false&leafLevelBrowse=false&ycord=0) (*Includes Deschler’s, Cannon’s, and Hinds’ Precedents; contains rulings made by the chair of the House of Representatives.*)
- [U.S. Statutes at Large](https://www.loc.gov/collections/statutes-at-large/) (*Digital copies of the U.S. Statutes at Large, from Congress 1 (1789) through Congress 81 (1950).*)
- [ASIL Electronic Resource Guide](http://www.asil.org/resources/electronic-resource-guide-erg) (*Electronic    resource guide that sets out basic international law search strategies and    lists resources on various topics.*)
- [Audiovisual Library of International Law](http://www.un.org/law/avl/) (*Contains documents, tapes - both audio and video  - and other materials on subjects of international law.*)
- [Australasian    Legal Information Institute Databases](http://www.austlii.edu.au/databases.html) (*AustLII    contains primary legal and legislative materials for Australia and New Zealand.*)
- [British and    Irish Legal Information Institute Databases](http://www.bailii.org/) (*BAILII    contains primary legal and legislative materials for England and Wales, Ireland, Northern Ireland, Scotland, United Kingdom, and the European Union.*)
- [Canadian Legal    Information Institute Databases](http://www.canlii.org/en/) (*CanLII contains primary legal and legislative materials for Canada.*)
- [Foreign Relations of the United States (FRUS)](http://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments) (*U.S. Department of State site presenting the official documentary historical record of major United States foreign policy decisions and significant diplomatic activity, primarily covering 1945 to 1980.*)
- [Human Rights Library](http://www1.umn.edu/humanrts/) (*Digital copies of core human rights documents, including several hundred human rights    treaties and other primary international human rights instruments.*)
- [Institute for Transnational Law Foreign Law Translations](http://www.utexas.edu/law/academics/centers/transnational/work_new/) (*English translations of French,    German, Austrian, and Israeli legal materials in the fields of    constitutional, administrative, contract and tort law.*)
- [London Gazette Archive](http://www.gazettes-online.co.uk/Home.aspx?geotype=London) (*An    official newspaper of record in the United Kingdom for publishing legal notices,    including insolvency (bankruptcy) notices.*)
- [NATLEX](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/natlex/natlex_browse.home?p_lang=en) (*Contains    over 55,000 records covering over 170 countries and territories on national labour, social security and related human rights legislation.*)
- [World    Legal Information Institute (WorldLII)](http://www.worldlii.org/cgi-bin/browse.pl) (*Provides access to worldwide law    from countries in six continents.*)
- [Congress.gov](http://www.congress.gov/) (*Contains full-text of legislation from the 103rd   Congress (1993) to the present and member profiles from the 93rd Congress   (1973) to the present.*)
- [Human  Rights Library](http://www1.umn.edu/humanrts/) (*Digital copies of core human rights documents,  including treaties and other primary international human rights instruments.*)
- [Indian  Affairs: Laws and Treaties](https://dc.library.okstate.edu/digital/collection/kapplers) (*Digital copies of documents dealing with the  legal status and laws, government relations, and treaties of North American  Indians.*)
- [Indigenous Law Portal](https://www.loc.gov/research-centers/law-library-of-congress/collections/indigenous-law/) (*Links to legal documents, including full-text constitutions, charters and, other legal material.*)
- [United States Treaty Series](https://www.loc.gov/research-centers/law-library-of-congress/researcher-resources/databases/) (*Digital copies of  historical treaties (1795-1945) compiled by Charles I. Bevans.*)
- [Federal Register](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/federal-register.php) (*Provides the full-text of the Federal Register, volumes 1-58, 1936-1993.*)
- [Regulations.gov](http://www.regulations.gov/#!home) (*Allows for browsing and searching of proposed and final federal regulations, submitted comments regarding proposed regulations, supporting agency documentation, and reports related to regulations.*)

### On-Site Only Access

- [Gale Legal Forms  Library](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000855%7ES9) (*Includes  thousands of state and federal legal forms, centered around the areas of  business, personal use, and litigation, which can be personalized by users.*)
- [Nexis Uni](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000623%7ES9) (*Comprehensive coverage of US federal and state case law, statutes and   regulations.  Includes secondary source materials such as law reviews,   newspapers, treatises and patent information. Also  includes Shepard’s Citations Service.*)
- [CQ.com](http://www.cq.com/) (*Congressional Quarterly, including Congressional  Weekly, provides in-depth legislative news and analysis of the United States  Congress.*)
- [LLMC Digital](http://ets.umdl.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?g=llmc;page=home) (*Searchable    databases of earlier primary U.S. federal and state government    documents as well as various foreign jurisdictions and international    organizations.*)
- [Making of Modern Law: Legal Treatises 1800 – 1926](http://galenet.galegroup.com/servlet/MOML;jsessionid=) (*Searchable    collection of Anglo-American legal treatises containing works from casebooks,    local practice manuals, form books, works for lay readers, pamphlets,    letters, speeches and more.*)
- [ProQuest Congressional](https://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000130%7ES9.) (*Provides    access to U.S. legislative information, including hearings, reports, prints,    documents, bills, laws, regulations, and CIS Legislative Histories (1969-present).*)
- [ProQuest Legislative Insight](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000927%7ES9) (*Provides various browsing and searching options for selected compiled legislative histories, for the 24th Congress (1835-1837) through the 112th Congress (2011-2013).*)
- [Supreme Court Library from HeinOnline](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Index?collection=usreports) (*Includes complete coverage of published cases in official sources from 1754 to the    last full calendar year for the United States Supreme Court.*)
- [United States Supreme Court Records and Briefs,    1832 - 1978 (Gale)](http://galenet.galegroup.com/servlet/SCRB?locID=loc_main) (*A collection of Supreme Court documents covering more than    150,000 distinct cases.*)
- [U.S. Congressional Serial Set (Readex)](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000440%7ES9) (*Contains    all the reports, documents, and journals of the United States Senate and    House of Representatives, from the 15th Congress (1817) through the 97th Congress (1982).*)
- [DOINet](http://www.doinet.com.br/logar.asp?c=5813675916239) (*DOINet provides public legal documents for Brazil.*)
- [Oxford Constitutions of the World](http://oxcon.ouplaw.com/) (*Contains    the full-text of constitutions from over 187 countries, including English    translations and introductory and comparative notes.*)
- [Index to Foreign    Legal Periodicals (via HeinOnline)](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Index?collection=iflp&set_as_cursor=clear) (*A multilingual subject index to legal articles and book reviews published in over 550 sources worldwide.*)
- [Max Planck Encyclopedia of Public International Law](http://opil.ouplaw.com/home/EPIL) (*Comprehensive work covering the central and essential topics in international law since the Peace of Westphalia in 1648.*)
- [HeinOnline](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Welcome) (*Offers a full-text searchable database of law    reviews and journals.*)
- [Index to Foreign    Legal Periodicals (via HeinOnline)](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Index?collection=iflp&set_as_cursor=clear) (*A multilingual subject index to    legal articles and book reviews published in over 550 sources worldwide.*)
- [Index to Legal    Periodicals & Books Full Text (1981-present)](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000392%7ES9) (*Covers over 1,000 legal journals,    yearbooks, law reviews, and more from the U.S., Canada, Great Britain, Ireland, Australia, and New Zealand.*)
- [Index to Legal    Periodicals Retrospective (1908-1981)](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000389%7ES9) (*Index    to over 750 legal periodicals, including law reviews, bar association    journals, and government publications.*)
- [LegalTrac](http://go.galegroup.com/ps/start.do?page=IdentityUserGroup.jsp&prodId=LT&userGroupName=loc_main&authCount=1&u=loc_main) (*Index to more than 2,400 titles including major law reviews, legal newspapers, bar    association journals and international legal journals.*)
- [Treaties  and Agreements Library from HeinOnline](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Index?collection=ustreaties) (*Includes both official and unofficial primary  treaty resources in addition to helpful guides.*)
- [CCH IntelliConnect](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1000674%7ES9) (*Includes federal, state, and international tax primary law materials such as regulations, administrative decisions, statutes, and treaties. Also includes secondary tax resources such as tax articles, practice tools, state and federal tax guides and reporters. Resources in the fields of accounting and audit and financial and estate planning are included.*)
- [Code of Federal Regulations/The Federal Register Collection (via HeinOnline)](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Index?collection=fedreg&set_as_cursor=clear) (*Provides search and browse options to the PDF of the Federal Register and Federal Register Index back to 1936; the Code of Federal Regulations (C.F.R.) back to 1938; and details on C.F.R. sections affected back to 1949.*)
- [CyberRegs](http://loc.cyberregs.com/) (*Provides the full-text of the US Code, Federal Register, Code of    Federal Regulations, state registers, state statutes and forms, and state    environmental, safety, health and transportation regulations.*)
- [ProQuest Regulatory Insight](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1002092%7ES9) (*Includes compiled regulatory "histories" of U.S. federal regulations promulgated pursuant to specific U.S. Public Laws. Covers U.S. federal administrative law histories for the period 1936-2017 organized by federal statute and Executive Order. This includes Federal Register documents, Code of Federal Regulations documents, and Executive Orders.*)

### Other Access Rights

- [Bluebook](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1001811%7ES9) (**Access for Law Library staff only**, *Comprehensive guide to legal citation in the United States*)
- [Bloomberg Law](http://eresources.loc.gov/record=e1002324%7ES9) (**Access  only available on one specific Library computer in the Law Library Reading Room**, *Practitioner  resources including, court dockets and documents, litigation analytics, sample  forms. Secondary sources including Bloomberg BNA publications (current  awareness sources and law reports), treatises from ABI, ABA, Wiley Press and  others. Includes US federal and state case law, statutes, and regulations. Also  includes BCite citator.*)
- [Westlaw Patron Access](http://www.westlaw.com/search/home.html?rs=IWLN1.0&vr=3.0&sp=004026439-4100) (**Access only available on Library computers in the Law  Library Reading Room; limit of 3 simultaneous users**, *Comprehensive coverage of US federal and state  case law, statutes, and regulations. Includes select secondary sources such as  American Law Reports,  legal encyclopedias, treatises, law review articles,  50 state surveys, legal forms, and Restatements. Also includes the citator  KeyCite.*)
- [Foreign Law Guide](http://referenceworks.brillonline.com/browse/foreign-law-guide) (**Access only available in the Law Library**, *Provides    an overview of individual legal systems with references to current sources of    codes and basic legislation for each jurisdiction.*)
- [Law nB – Korean Law    Database](http://loc.lawnb.com/) (**Access only available in the Law Library**, *Provides access to cases, statutes    and other legal references for Korea.*)
- [RDB de Rechtsdatenbank](http://www.rdb.at/rdbstart.html?browser=MSIE&rnd=0.6218716425791699) (**Access only available in the Law Library**, *Provides access to a large number    of Austrian legal journals, collections of cases, and other resources related    to the laws of Austria.*)
- [Find It! Article Finder](https://www.loc.gov/pubrr/findit-articlefinder.html) (**Internet**, *Library of Congress tool to help you locate the    full-text of an article by providing citation information.*)

---

None of these are structured, however. It seems we are a far ways away from that.

From what I recall from school, most of the stuff is private in Lexus Nexus or other [competitively similar legal databases](https://www.quora.com/Who-are-the-major-competitors-of-LexisNexis).

[Here](https://www.datacoalition.org/new-proposal-transform-u-s-statutes-at-large-into-open-data/) is a project for converting US Code to structured data (2015). And according to that, [here](http://uscode.house.gov/download/download.shtml) is the US Code in XML.